# Constructing a linked list based stack that can contain both primitive and user defined data types

Tags: c++

I need to make a stack based on a linked list structure that can have multiple nodes of differing data types, so, for example, one node could be a character that can link to another data type that's been defined by the user.

I currently have made my stack DS like this:

```
template <class pointType>
class stackType {
    private:
        struct StackNode {
            StackNode *next;
            pointType data;
        };
        StackNode *top;
```

and my custom data type like this

```
template<typename T>
class pointType {
private:
    T x;
    T y;
```

After this, I can produce an infix expression that can be calculated using yet another stack, the problem is I don't think I can do that since I have to define what data type the stack will use by default.

since theres confusion heres my lab question verbatim

```
Practices on Application of Stacks.
1. Modify the class PointType by overloading these arithemetic operators.
– = (we have done in Lab 3)
– - : subtract two points (X = X1 -X2, Y = Y1 -Y2)
– * : multiply two points (X = X1 *X2, Y = Y1*Y2)
– / : divide two points (X = X1 / X2, Y = Y1 / Y2)
2. Design a class StackType by modifying the class StackPOINTS in which each element can be
any type, such as primitive data types and the type of the user defined data type: PointType.
3. Test your design by building:
– an integer stack
– a floating point stack
– a character stack
– a string stack
– an arithmetic operator stack
– a pointType stack
– an infix expression of A + B * C / ( D - E )
```

More additional details would be I've gotten most of these working, I can make a stack of any type given the stack only uses that type only, what throws me off is having to set up overloaded operators and the infix expression, which clearly implies I need to do something that contains pointType data and characters for the operator, and possibly needs to be read and calculated using the method of solving infix expressions with stacks, the problem is I don't quite know how I'd be able to do that because, again, I can't really figure out how to have two types of elements linked in a stack

Comment: Presuming that you haven't yet covered `std::variant` in class, the most straightforward solution would be a stack of smart pointers to an abstract base class, with all operations implemented in the subclasses. But in all cases, I would expect that your homework will be based on material that has been presented in class. So, what have you learned in class, that will be relevant to this homework assignment?

Comment: I don't think my professor cares as long as it produces the desired result, honestly they are bad at communicating but that's been the unspoken rule, my only limitation seems to be I might not be able to use anything introduced beyond c++11 since thats what our compiler can do in class

Comment: How many different datatypes do you need to be able to store?

Comment: *multiple nodes of differing data types* all in one stack or in multiple stacks, each with a single contained data type? Multiple stacks is significantly easier and more in line with the typical solution for a stack-based calculator.

Comment: Please post your assignment verbatim. It isn't at all certain that you are interpreting it correctly.

Comment: my professor's language isn't english so I'm extrapolating this is what she wants, i edited the post